# Object array in jQuery tmpl

Tags: jquery-templates

As a very simplified example I have an object array like this:

```
var myObjects = {};
myObjects['keyString'] = {
    value1 : 'someValue'
}
```

How can I get object array to work with jquery tmpl?

My template looks something like this:

```
<li>
   ${value1} 
</li>
```

Is it possible to get this to work?

I have no problem making it work with an array like this:

```
var myObjects = [];
myObjects[0] = {
    value1 : 'someValue'
}
```

But I really need it to work with the first example.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you call, in the line 2, a wrong name of your Object.

```
myObjets['keyString'] -> myObjects['keyString']
```

You forgot a "c"

Comment: That was not really my problem, just a typo in the sample. Sorry!